# How to make a drupal site read-only

Tags: users

I want to make a frozen copy of a drupal site (D6) and prevent users from making any changes whatsoever (except for the system adminstrator, if possible).  How can I do that?  I want to keep the usernames.

Hiding the login block is easy, but the login url is still available.  I've tried disabling all passwords by setting the hash to 'x', but still, someone could recover access via email, and login.  So, I want to prevent password recovery too.  I could alter all email addresses to something invalid, such as {uid}@example.com.  But I don't want the system to even attempt to send email to these addresses.

The site is used for a yearly campaign/contest.  I want to keep results of previous contests online, for reference, at a different url, and I don't want anybody changing anything.  Ideally, I would structure the site so it keeps previous contest results in the same database, but that requires extensive changes which I don't have the time to do.

Comment: _but the login url is still available_ ...yeah, that's kind of important - how else are _you_ going to log in to administer it?

Comment: You can redirect non admin users back to the homepage..

Comment: Why do you want to block the login in the first place? Wouldn’t it be sufficient to remove all edit rights from users but still allow them to login?

Comment: I want to block login as a safeguard to avoid changes, and to avoid confusing users who may think they are using the real site.  This is a snapshot in time of the real website.  I don't want users to be confused about which website they're logged-in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Disable all user accounts apart from admin.
2. Disable new users from registering new accounts.
3. Edit permissions as necessary.

Now only admin can login, and anonymous users won't have permission to edit anything.

Answer (score 2):

Simply block all the user except the user #1.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I missed, but the previous answer was first and it describes the whole procedure.